# How to change a to-delete-range without selecting it

Tags: vba, excel

I tried everything which come to my mind to rewrite this code without the selection part.

```
Worksheets(3).Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ListName).Range.Select 'Listname is a string-variable
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1), ActiveCell.Offset(-1)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Worksheets(2).Activate
MsgBox "Set-creation was canceled.", vbCritical
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Try `Worksheets(3).ListObjects(ListName).Range.Offset(-1).Resize(2).Delete shift:=xlUp`.  I do not work with tables much, so I am unsure of it working.

Comment: I recommend reading through [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: @Sir l33tname: my problem was that i tried to figure out how to write the code without .select. I tried to manage it with address resize and whatever. I mostly try to improve my vba-Skills by experimentiation but i did not hit the point this time.

Comment: @BruceWayne thx for the advice! I'll do so later.

Comment: @Scott Craner: I'll give it a try. If it should work i'll tell you.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Thx! It worked. Now i know the .resize method too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Worksheets(3).Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ListName).Range.Select 'Listname is a string-variable
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1), ActiveCell.Offset(-1)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Worksheets(2).Activate
MsgBox "Set-creation was canceled.", vbCritical
```

---

Can be re-written as:

---

```
With Sheets(3)
    .Range(.ListObjects(ListName).Range.Offset(1), .ListObjects(ListName).Range.Offset(-1)).Delete xlUp
End With    
Sheets(2).Activate    
MsgBox "Set-creation was canceled.", vbCritical
```

---

You don't need to `.Select` anything in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) especially when dealing with a `Range` object - all it's properties and methods can be accessed directly.

Instead of:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Value = "Test"
```

Consider:

```
Range("A1").Value = "Test"
```

This is better coding and in long procedures will run much faster. The other advantage is that you don't have to keep a track of what the `Selection` is when debugging or improving the code.

Comment: I already heard of the fact, that there is no activate or select necessary in VBA-Code ever. Im not as deep in the coding as i wish, so i try to improve it. I'll try your code later.

Thx at all for the given informations and advices!